# Question about auto-versioned static content

Tags: javascript, css, static-content, auto-versioning

From my understanding, auto-versioning as a method of forcing updates of static content will cause unique files to be cached every time the content is updated, potentially leading to many "copies" of the content saved, all but one of which will never be used.

Is this ever a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Caches expire data when they get full as well as when the time runs out on them.